# Handle swipe and click differently for closing DrawerLayout

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have a `DrawerLayout` that contains a list.
I want to disable the the swipe-close on it so the ways to close it would be clicking on the back button or clicking the inactive area of the drawer.

Is there a good practice implementing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aakash Goyal's answer have done half the trick:

setting the drawer lock mode with `DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED` Indeed disabled gestures exactly as I wanted. However on that case it was also disabling the Back button press to close the drawer.

So I've also added code for intercepting the back press and close the drawer:

```
mDrawerLayout.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() 
{           
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT))
            {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also, I've changed the lock mode to unlocked when the drawer get closed - as I still want to allow it to open on swipe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setDrawerLockMode()` function of the Navigation Drawer with `DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED` as parameter to disable gestures